# numpy recarray minimum differences

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I have a numpy recarray I want to find record where difference of 1st element and last element of record is maximum.

can someone suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up:

```
import numpy
ra = numpy.recarray((10,), 'int,int,int')
```

Find the index of the maximum of the difference between first field and last field.

```
idx = numpy.argmax(ra['f0']-ra['f2'])
```

Retrieve the record using that index

```
print ra[idx]
```